# Add limit to coccon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a secondaryparents table and I want to limit the add button to just 1 secondaryparent.

```
<div id ='secondaryparents'>
  <%= f.fields_for :secondaryparents do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'secondaryparent_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Secondary Parent', f, :secondaryparents, limit: 1 %>
</div>
```

I tried adding limit: 1 but it doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why you use dynamic nested forms for one attribute???
It seems you don't need cocoon here at all.

Comment: @greenif earlier we need more secondary parents but now just one. thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // console.log('dfdsfdsf')
  // limits the number of categories
  $('#secondaryparents').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    $('#add-category a').hide();
  });

  $('#secondaryparents').on('cocoon:after-remove', function() {
    $('#add-category a').show();
  });

    if (<%= @parent.secondaryparents.length %>) {
    $('#add-category a').hide();
  }

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel action with JS events

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#canceling-a-callback

Something like that:

```
$('#secondaryparents').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(event, insertedItem) {
  if($('css seletor').length > 1){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Secondary Parent', f, :secondaryparents, id: "secondaryparents" %> <script>
$('#secondaryparents').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(event, insertedItem) {
  if($('css seletor').length > 1){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
</script>  I tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach is to hide the link to add new items when the requested number is reached.

An easy way to do this is to use the `cocoon:after-insert` and `cocoon:after-remove` callbacks, count the number of items inserted when triggered and hide/show the `link_to_add_association` link when needed.

> Note: since this is imho a UX choice, it is not implemented as such in cocoon as a feature. I believe it is a best practice to not show clickable things which we know beforehand are not going to give any results. But opinions and practices differ :)

Example implementation: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/How-to-limit-the-number-of-nested-fields

Comment: Please check the update above. I tried what you suggested but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: If I see correctly, you now have two html elements with the id `secondaryparents` on the page? (the link-to-add-association and the containing div?). The page will render correctly, but when you try to "reach" the element with a specific id it is not defined which you will find. The link? the div? Fix that first, the rest of the code looks good.